# Sonic Boom VS Scud Missle Concussion wave

Tags: forces

On Jan. 19 1991 at approx. 0300 I was asleep in my sleeping bag on my Cot at an undisclosed location during Operation Desert Storm. We heard an enormous explosion and instantaneously felt as if the all of the air was sucked out of my sleeping bag and being punched in the chest. The Air raid siren went off after the event as we all grabbed our gear and ran for the bunkers. We were told that we had been hit by a SCUD Missile and to go to MOPP level 4 (Full Chemical Protection). Several minutes later we were given the all clear and told what we had experienced was a sonic boom from a fighter jet. Is it plausible that a sonic boom can create this experience?

Comment: You are looking for two booms and a **very** low flying jet if you go the sonic route.

Comment: In the Case narrative dated Oct. 25, 2001 from the US Dept. of Defense. It states that some Veterans heard 2 nearly simultaneous booms. (I only recall one, but I was sleeping). It also states there were 2 aircraft but not occupying the same airspace. Altitude of both aircraft exceeded 29,000 ft. This was the answer to 2 sonic booms.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Picture credit: [Supersonic Aircraft](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=748925)

Firstly, I am glad it was you and not me that was involved.

The sonic boom is produced by  the wing's leading edge and trailing edge wave. The aircraft wing undergoes a supersonic pressure change due both to it's motion and the wing loading it experiences. This causes it to expand into the bow and tail waves, they merge together as they reach ground level. This is why we hear a double sonic boom. My earlier comment was wrong, a low flying supersonic aircraft produces multiple bangs.

But still, your description of what you felt is much more severe than the complaints made by those people who owned property under the flight path of the Concorde SST. Flying at 30,000 feet resulted in broken windows and roof tiles being dislodged.

This article [Oklahoma City Sonic Boom Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma_City_sonic_boom_tests) also confirms the effects of overpressure on structures, which were comparable to the Concorde effects, and not as powerful as your question lists.

Comment: Thank you, I was proud to serve. Just not overly excited about being lied to by my Government. In conclusion, an F-3 Tornado aircraft could not have caused the physical experience we felt?

Comment: Only you know what you experienced. I was going to say, but it is wrong, that being woken suddenly makes your senses race, but given where you were, and the training you had, you would have been far more able to judge events than I would have been.  If you look up **overpressure from sonic boom** on Wikipedia, it would seem to me to eliminate an aircraft as the cause. But please read the page and judge for yourself as to the effects of a boom compared to your experience.  Regards.